# How to traverse backwards in a table from the last column to second column in selenium using xpath?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, datatable

There's a table on the UI with dynamic number of rows.Only one row at a certain point of time contains an icon , means , as we complete the task of a certain row by clicking the icon , the icon moves to some other row.

What I wish to do is , fetch the task name from second column of the row on the basis that icon is present in the same row in the last column

```
//*[contains(@title,'icon')]/ancestor::*
```

The structure of the code for a single column is like :

```
<td role="gridecell">
  <span class="Actions">Actions </span>
  <span id="something">
    <a> icon </a>
  </span>
```

Now on the basis of this icon presence , I wish to traverse back to the second column of the same row.

The row structure is like :

```
<tr data-row="1" role="row">
  <td role="gridcell">
    <span class="Name of action"> </span>
      <span id="some id">
        <span id="some id">
          <span id="">data to be fetched particular name </span>
        </span>
      </span>
```

The entire row structure would be something like :

```
<tr data-row="1">
  <td role="gridcell"/>
  <td role="gridcell"/>
  <td role="gridcell">
    <span class="some name">
    <span class="Name of action"> </span>
          <span id="some id">
            <span id="some id">
              <span id="">data to be fetched particular name </span>
            </span>
     </span>
     </td>
  <td role="gridcell"/>
  <td role="gridcell"/>
  <td role="gridcell">
  <span class="Actions">Actions </span>
      <span id="something">
        <a> icon </a>
      </span>  
  </td>
```

I wish to get the value from second column of the table on the basis of the icon presence in the last column of the table.

Comment: Instead of partial html blocks can you update the question with the html of the entire row?

Comment: Hi Debanjan , I can't do that because of organisation privacy policies

Comment: I am not sure but the HTML of the rows are still not that super clear to me to construct a canonical answer.

Comment: Hi Debanjan , I have made some changes and put it together , if it works?

Comment: Are you trying to locate the node `<span id="">data to be fetched particular name </span>` with respect to the node `<a> icon </a>`?

Comment: Still your _the entire row structure_ is malformed as one of the `<span>` tag isn't closed.

Comment: Yes, I'm  trying to locate the node <span id="">data to be fetched particular name </span> with respect to the node <a> icon </a>

Answer (score 1):

You can look for a row with descendant element with `icon` text (not title). From there you can use index to get the second column if you don't have unique identifier

```
//tr[//a[contains(.,'icon')]]/td[2]
```